# How to communicate between two different applications (Web Application and Console Application) using Ctr+c , Ctr+v , Entre

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, keyevent, qkeyevent

I have two application one is a web application and the onther one is a console application,
the Console application generates a Data and that Data must be transfered to the webapplication, i tried to use the APIs to communicate between them but I find that I have Many users of my webapplication so I have many destinations and in this case I can't use APIs.

The only solution is that I need to use the Key events;
My question is : how I can use Ctr+c in my console application to copy my data, and how my Webapplication can Ctr+v + Entre : to get that Data from my console application

Comment: Hi, 1-Where are your console and web application data stored? 2-Can you provide some codes and some snapshots of your application environment, please?

Comment: Do you want your application to listen for ctrl-c directly? without requiring the user to select some text first? Ctrl-C is treated as a break signal by default, I would not expect that to put text into the clipboard, I would just be mad that it does not stop the application. I would consider either just copy pasting text, or use some communication protocol instead, http/mqtt/rabbitMQ/gRPC, etc, there are plenty to chose from.

Comment: the data is stored in a database, I was thinking to use the database as mean of connection between my two application, that my console application put Data in specific table and the weapplication get data from that table , but that solution was eliminated. the copy task is easy but how the console application will Ctr+v + Entr in the webapplication ; How it will know the right place please ?

Comment: the solution can be inspired from DMC lazer system , it scans the code then copie it and  paste it in the screen